# Proving congruence modulo .

Tags: elementary-number-theory

*Can you guide me through this proof*.
Prove n<sup>2</sup>≡(7−n)<sup>2</sup>(mod 7). where n is an integeer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$n^2 \equiv (7-n)^2 \pmod 7$ if and only if $7$ divides $n^2 - (7 - n)^2$.

So we expand:

$$\begin{align}n^2 - (7-n)^2 &= n^2 - 49 + 14n -n^2 \\&= 7(-7 + 2n)\end{align}$$

which is clearly divisible by $7$.

It follows that the congruence equivalence must hold true.

Comment: oh yeah true. Didn't think of it that way at first. Thanks very much

Comment: No problem. Since you are new to Math.SE: Do remember to mark any solution posted in response to your questions via the tick beside it, if you found it useful and sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Think of this in the following way:

$7 \equiv 0$ (mod $7$).

If $a \equiv b$ mod $7$ then $a^2 \equiv b^2$.

So, $(7-n) \equiv -n$ implies that $(7-n)^2 \equiv n^2$